# How to get all functions and top-level names from Javascript

Tags: javascript, static, static-analysis, introspection, ffi

I'm trying to write a program that will automatically generate FFI files between Javascript and another language (Elm).

I was wondering, are there any tools which can take a Javascript module and list all the functions avaliable, possibly with their number of arguments? If it can only do top-level functions, that's okay, I realize that this gets complicated with closures and thunks and such.

Is it possible to do something like that from within Javascript as a form of introspection, or would I have to use some sort of parser/analyser? If so, are there any such tools that exist and are fairly mature/easy to use?

EDIT: I realize that JavaScript is dynamic. My main goal is to generate FFI interfaces for libraries and APIs, so the things which are there should be fairly easy to reason about statically, since they're not going to be changed dynamically. I'm okay if it's imperfect, I'm looking for a tool to ease my writing of boilerplate rather than something that is guaranteed to be bulletproof.

Comment: You'd have to parse *and execute* the code in order to really know what it's doing. JavaScript is a dynamic language, so there's a definite limit to how much you can do with static analysis.

Comment: *And even then*, if the code can run "in the wild" in the context where unknown other code has run, you can't really know you're learning exactly what it does in all cases.

Comment: Okay, but you wouldn't have to execute the code to see what function names were globally accessible initially. I'm willing to make the reasonable assumption that a library I'm writing an FFI for isn't going to remove function definitions from its global function. Like I said, I'm using this to generate FFIs, so my main concern is getting globally-accessible API function names, rather than every single function which could possibly be generated by the JS.

Comment: No, that's not really true. It's common for libraries to have *no* declared-as-global functions. Instead, they dynamically bind values to global symbols programmatically.

Comment: Okay... would there then be a tool which could do the library initialization and then iterate through the available functions?

Comment: I'm not aware of anything, but there's no reason I in particular should be. In other words, my ignorance doesn't mean much. One simple approach might be to load the code into some sandbox, let it run, and then check the global state. That might be doable in Node.js I suppose.

Comment: it is possible to do it in nodejs, i posted some scripts

Answer (score 2):

Something that is going to be tricky for you is that there are many different conventions for creating Javascript modules: putting variables in a global scope, returning a table from a file, etc. Module creation is also pretty dynamic so it might be easier to do things from inside Javascript.

Assuming you can get your hands in a javascript object corresponding to your module, you can inspect it with a `for in` loop:

```
var myModule = ...
for(var key in myModule){
  if( Object.hasOwnProperty.call(myModule, key) ){
    var func = myModule[key];
    ...
  }
}
```

To check if the object property is a function, you can use the `typeof` operator:

```
if(typeod func == "function")
```

and to see the number of arguments you can check the length property of the function:

```
func.length
```

Note that the number of arguments might be wrong if the function is variadic or otherwise gets arguments from the `arguments` array. But something checking the source text is also going to get that wrong...

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to do it in node.js. Because of security reasons while runing a script with:
`node script.js` one can not see functions or variables in `global` object provided by nodejs but while running a script with `node -e "some script"` one has access to functions and variables from `global object`.

So I wrote 3 scripts.

1. Reads the file that needs to be parsed (scriptThatNeedsToBeParsed.js) and the interpret file (interpretFile.js). Combines them and creates a process with node -e combinedFileContents
2. Script that needs to be parsed
3. Script used to interpret parsed file

**scriptThatNeedsToBeParsed.js:**

```
function A(a,b,c){}
var abc;
function T(){}
```

**readFile.js:**

I am reading the file that needs to be parsed and I define 2 variables:
`START_FROM_THIS_OBJECT` before the content of the file and `END_TO_THIS_OBJECT` after the content of the file. So later I would know from where to where to search functions and variables.

```
if(process.argv.length !=4 )
{
    console.log("Usage %s <input-file> <interpret-file>",process.argv[0]);
    process.exit(0);
}
var input_file = process.argv[2];
var interpret_file = process.argv[3];
var fs = require('fs');
var fileToParse = ";var START_FROM_THIS_OBJECT;";
fileToParse += fs.readFileSync(input_file, "utf8");
var interpretFile = fs.readFileSync(interpret_file, "utf8");
fileToParse += ";var END_TO_THIS_OBJECT;";
var script = fileToParse + interpretFile;
var child = require('child_process').execFile('node', 
[ 
    '-e', script, 
], function(err, stdout, stderr) { 
    console.log(stdout); 
});
```

**interpretFile.js:**
I search for functions and variables just "between" the 2 control variables defined above

```
var printObjects = false;
for(var item in global)
{
    if(item == "END_TO_THIS_OBJECT")
    {
        printObjects = false;
    }
    if(printObjects)
    {

        if(typeof(global[item]) == "function")
        {
            console.log("Function :%s with nr args: %d",item,global[item].length); 
        }
        else
        {
            console.log("Variable :%s with value: %d",item,global[item]); 
        }
    }
    if(item == "START_FROM_THIS_OBJECT")
    {
        printObjects = true;
    }
}
```

The last part of the `global` object from nodejs: `console.log(global);`

```
     module:
      { id: '[eval]',
        exports: {},
        parent: undefined,
        filename: 'E:\\LOCAL\\xampp\\htdocs\\nodejs\\[eval]',
        loaded: false,
        children: [],
        paths:
         [ 'E:\\LOCAL\\xampp\\htdocs\\nodejs\\node_modules',
           'E:\\LOCAL\\xampp\\htdocs\\node_modules',
           'E:\\LOCAL\\xampp\\node_modules',
           'E:\\LOCAL\\node_modules',
           'E:\\node_modules' ] },
     __dirname: '.',
     require:
      { [Function: require]
        resolve: [Function],
        main: undefined,
        extensions: { '.js': [Function], '.json': [Function], '.node': [Function] },
        registerExtension: [Function],
        cache: {} },
     START_FROM_THIS_OBJECT: undefined,<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
     A: [Function: A],
     abc: undefined,
     T: [Function: T],
     END_TO_THIS_OBJECT: undefined,<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
```

---

I run the script with : `node readFile.js scriptThatNeedsToBeParsed.js interpretFile.js`
**This is the output:**
Function :A with nr args: 3
Variable :abc with value: NaN
Function :T with nr args: 0